# Scrape data with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am going to scrape the Pararius.nl as a practice with scrapy but when I start crawling it returns the fairlane protection, how can I pass it? Do I need any tools? please help with one example

```
def parse(self, response):
    url = 'https://www.pararius.nl/{deal_type}/nederland/p-{page}/'

        for deal_type in ['huurwoningen', 'koopwoningen']:
            for i in range(1, 2):
                yield scrapy.Request(url.format(deal_type=deal_type, page=i), callback=self.parse_pages,cookies=self.cookies,
                                     headers=self.h, method='GET', cb_kwargs={'deal_type': deal_type})
    
    
    def parse_pages(self, response, deal_type):
        print(response.url)
        return
```

Comment: You will likely have to use some sort of browser automation tool.

Comment: @Alexander I am new in python, I tried selenium but did not succeed, do you have any example?

Comment: Is the url you are trying to use correct as after moving through the pages manually it comes up with "https://www.pararius.nl/huurwoningen/nederland/page-10", using just p-{number of page} seems to just result in the same first page coming up

Comment: also do you have a view of what is actually printed when you run this?

Comment: It is right, I am testing the result on firt page, but it return this url : 
https://www.pararius.nl/cgi-bin/fl/captcha @Hillygoose

Comment: @parastoo can you edit your code to show your whole spider?

Comment: To bypass protections, you can use a legit User-Agent in your headers, manage cookies properly, and consider using a tool like Splash for JavaScript-heavy websites. However, remember that scraping protected sites could be against the site's Terms of Service.

Comment: @Hillygoose this is my whole code, I want to get a response of  page but it redirects to recaptcha page

Comment: I can add cookies in scrapy but I want to add it automatically , this is a practice and I saw it in other sites as well, so I am aware of terms of service @MustaphaHadid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to paginate and collect data from the page without any issues.
as I see in your URL you using `p-` but as I see on the website it should be `page-`

here is code I've using for it:

```
def parse(self, response):
    url = 'https://www.pararius.nl/{deal_type}/nederland/page-{page}/'
    # 'koopwoningen'
    for deal_type in ['huurwoningen']:
        for i in range(1, 2):
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url.format(deal_type=deal_type, page=i),
                callback=self.parse_pages,
                method='GET',
            )

def parse_pages(self, response):
    for row in response.css('li.search-list__item'):
        href = row.css('a.listing-search-item__link--depiction::attr(href)').get()
        if href:
            yield {
                'seacrh_url': response.url,
                'url': 'https://pararius.nl' + href,
                'title': row.xpath(
                    './/div[contains(@class, "listing-search-item__sub-title\'")]/text()').get().strip()
            }

    page = response.meta.get('page', 2)
    if 'page-' in response.url:
        next_url = re.sub(r'page-\d+', f'page-{page}', response.url)
    else:
        next_url = response.url.strip('/') + f'/page-{page}'
    page += 1
    if page < 10:
        yield scrapy.Request(
            next_url,
            callback=self.parse_pages,
            method='GET',
            meta={'page': page}
        )
```

additional settings I've used:

```
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36'
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
```

and this is example of result I've received:

```
{"seacrh_url": "https://www.pararius.nl/huurwoningen/nederland/page-2", "url": "https://pararius.nl/studio-te-huur/breda/60de7cf7/vredenburchstraat", "title": "4811 RD Breda (Boeimeer)"},
{"seacrh_url": "https://www.pararius.nl/huurwoningen/nederland/page-2", "url": "https://pararius.nl/appartement-te-huur/eindhoven/7035fc54/aalsterweg", "title": "5615 CH Eindhoven (Looiakkers)"},
{"seacrh_url": "https://www.pararius.nl/huurwoningen/nederland/page-2", "url": "https://pararius.nl/appartement-te-huur/rotterdam/a5eba2a3/herman-gorterstraat", "title": "3061 SM Rotterdam (Kralingen West)"},
```

for `zah.nl`
additional lib is required `pip install undetected-chromedriver`

you can use the following:

```
import re
import time

import scrapy

import undetected_chromedriver as UC


class ZahSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'zah'
    allowed_domains = ['www.zah.nl']
    start_urls = ['https://www.zah.nl/te-koop/?page=1']

    headers = {
        'authority': 'www.zah.nl',
        'accept':     'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
        'accept-language': 'uk-UA,uk;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        options = uc.ChromeOptions()
        driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.get('https://www.zah.nl/te-koop/?page=1')
        time.sleep(5)

        cookies_list = driver.get_cookies()
        self.cookies_dict = {}
        for cookie in cookies_list:
            self.cookies_dict[cookie['name']] = cookie['value']
        driver.quit()

        yield scrapy.Request(
            url='https://www.zah.nl/te-koop/?page=1',
            cookies=self.cookies_dict,
            headers=self.headers,
            callback=self.parse
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        for row in response.css('div.result'):
            yield {
                'title': row.css('a > h2::text').get(),
                'url': row.css('a::attr(href)').get()
            }

        page = response.meta.get('page', 2)
        if page < 5:
            next_url = re.sub(r'page=\d+', f'page={page}', response.url)
            page += 1
           yield scrapy.Request(
                url=next_url,
                cookies=self.cookies_dict,
                headers=self.headers,
                meta={'page': page},
               callback=self.parse
            )
```

Comment: The site is updated today, they added page and removed fairelane so you can see links now , 
I would like to find the solution for this challenge, another site is zah.nl that has fairlane right now

Comment: @parastoo, added logic for `zah.nl`

Answer (score 2):

You should try using Selenium to bypass the fairlane protection that you mentioned (if that is the issue with the code).

First, install the scrapy-selenium package:

```
pip install scrapy-selenium
```

Then, modify your Scrapy spider to use SeleniumRequest instead of the regular Scrapy.Request:

```py
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest

def start_requests(self):
    url = 'https://www.pararius.nl/{deal_type}/nederland/p-{page}/'

    for deal_type in ['huurwoningen', 'koopwoningen']:
        for i in range(1, 2):
            yield SeleniumRequest(
                url = url.format(deal_type = deal_type, page = i),
                callback = self.parse_pages,
                cookies = self.cookies,
                headers = self.h,
                method = 'GET',
                cb_kwargs = {'deal_type': deal_type},
                wait_time = 3
            )

def parse_pages(self, response, deal_type):
    # Get Selenium web driver from response object
    driver = response.meta['driver']

    # Grab modified response from the web driver
    page_html = driver.page_source
    pageResponseObj = Selector(text = page_html)

    print(response.url)
    return
```

In the `.start_requests()` method, we use `SeleniumRequest` with a `wait_time` parameter of 3 seconds. This tells Selenium to wait for 3 seconds before moving on, giving the page time to load and bypassing the fairlane protection.

**Note:** I wasn't sure what indentation level the method `.parse_pages()` that you have lies in, so I just wrote the code how I think it would work. Also, I cannot properly test this code because it's written as part of a class, and you didn't give us the whole code for context. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your response, how did you obtain cookies in codes?
I also have other error : KeyError: 'driver'

Comment: @parastoo I did not obtain the cookies. In your provided case, I had deemed it unnecessary. I can help you with that if that's what you want though. As for that error, it can happen for multiple reasons. Most of the time though, it's because you don't have `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = { 'scrapy_selenium.SeleniumMiddleware': 800 }` in your project settings file. Tell me if that fixed it or if you need help with that. There maybe other reasons too but let's take it step by step.

Comment: I have the same response again , it returns the recaptcha page